# React native expo background location not working

Tags: react-native, location, expo

I'm newbiee in react native, I'm using expo I'm trying to get user location if app is in the background or killed. I used Taskmanager but I don't why it's not working. when app is running in foreground it is working fine but when app is in background or killed it's not giving me location.

I'm using Location from expo-location

```
const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = "background-location-task";

componentDidMount = async () => {

        this._getLocationAsync();
  };

_getLocationAsync = async () => {
    try {
      //ask permission of user for location
      let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

      //check the location setting
      const permissionStaatus = await Location.getProviderStatusAsync();
      const newStatus = permissionStaatus.locationServicesEnabled;

      //if phone location is disabled
      if (!newStatus) {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        Alert.alert(
          "Error",
          "Please Turn On you'r Location",
          [
            {
              text: "OK",
              onPress: this.openSetting
            }
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
      }
      // if location setting is enabled
      else {
        //if status is granted or not
        if (status !== "granted") {
          this.setState({
            errorMessage: "Permission to access location was denied"
          });
          return;
        } else {
          await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
            accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
            timeInterval: 3000,
            distanceInterval: 1
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      let status = await Location.getProviderStatusAsync();
      if (!status.locationServiceEnabled) {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        navigation.navigate("Site");
        // console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };



TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, async ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // Error occurred - check `error.message` for more details.
    return;
  }
 if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
  const location = locations.map(location => {
   let newLocation = Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location.coords)
        .then(data => {
          data.map(location => {
            axios.post(
              "http://192.168.0.1/api/account/saveUserLocation",
              location
            );
          })

        })
    })
}
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable sticky notification for android, the newer versions of android OS behave differently.
**Since Android(8.0)**

You have to use a sticky notification to enable your app stay in foreground.
You need to pass these options to the `startLocationUpdatesAsync`

```
 foregroundService: {
   notificationTitle: 'Your title',
   notificationBody: 'Notification Body'
 },
 pausesUpdatesAutomatically: false,
}
```

The `pausesUpdatesAutomatically` is for IOS, if you want your App to restart if killed.

**UPDTE**
Task manager also works in bare expo apps now, from sdk v37

Comment: my notification is being removed when app is swipe closed. Can you please guide m e on how to make notification sticky?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run `ajax` when the app is on the app `background`. `TaskManager` is the storage of a `location` in the repository. So if you want to get a `location` when your app is dead,try update the `location`.

**App.js**

```js
TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, async ({data, error}) => {
     if(error){
         return;
     }
     if(data){
        try{
            const { locations } = data;
            console.log("locations :" + locations);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('newlocation',data); //maybe it work
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
}
```

Updatedlocation

```js
updatedLocation = async() => {
     const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
     let isRegistered = await 
          TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME);
     if(isRegistered && status=='granted'){
            await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
                accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
                timeInterval: 2500,
                distanceInterval: 5,
                showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: false
            });
     }
     ... more code
}
...
// get localstorage data
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('newlocation');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

Comment: Can't you get a location value?

Comment: No, It's not working if app is in background or killed, I'm using android phone

Comment: which version of android you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I used the `foregroundService` option for the `startLocationUpdatesAsync` method as it says in the docs:

> Use this option to put the location service into a foreground state, which will make location updates in the background as frequent as in the foreground state. As a downside, it requires a sticky notification, so the user will be aware that your app is running and consumes more resources even if backgrounded. **(Available since Android 8.0)**

This is how it looks like on my code:

```
Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, { 
    accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
    timeInterval: LOCATION_TIME_INTERVAL,
    distanceInterval: LOCATION_DISTANCE_INTERVAL,
    foregroundService: {
        notificationTitle: LOCATION_TITLE,
        notificationBody: LOCATION_SUBTITLE
    }
});
```

Comment: my notification is being removed when app is swipe closed. Can you please guide m e on how to make notification sticky?

Answer (score 0):

ask the user to turn off the battery optimization for the which it pauses your app in background after some time.
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).